# Converting a long date to UK short date format dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: javascript, date

How can I get the long date:

```
Mon Mar 5 00:00:00 EST 2012
```

into the UK standard of (dd/mm/yyyy)

resulting in:

```
05/03/2012
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
function changedateformat(input) {
  var d = new Date(input);
  return [d.getDate(), d.getMonth()+1, d.getFullYear()].join('/');
}
```

Also check [Formatting a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

**EDIT:-**

As pointed out in comments you may add this condition to print the dates with 0.

```
if (month.length == 1)
    {
        month = "0" + month;
    }

    day = day + "";

    if (day.length == 1)
    {
        day = "0" + day;
    }
```

[DEMO JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/f6k3H/13/)

Comment: It looks like it works, but I need the zeros in front of the digits. Yours will works as 5/3/2012, but I need 05/03/2012

Comment: @JasonKelly:- Updated my answer. Hope that works for you! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/)

```
alert(Date.parse('Mon Mar 5 00:00:00 EST 2012').toString('dd/mm/yyyy'));
```

Comment: Was hoping to avoid adding on lengthy libraries

Answer (score 0):

Modified from [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript/10685571#10685571)

```
function dateToDMY(date) {
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    return ''+(d <= 9 ? '0' + d : d)+'/'+ (m<=9 ? '0' + m : m) + '/' + y;
}
```

Comment: didn't work mm was 00

Comment: What are you talking about?  Worked fine for me...

http://jsfiddle.net/f9WXC/